# Elements appending at every index in nested loop

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

```
>>> a = [[]]*10
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[0]
[]  
>>> a[0].append([1,2])
>>> a
[[[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]]
>>> b = [[] for _ in range(10)]
>>> b
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> b[0].append([1,2])
>>> b
[[[1, 2]], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Why the first nested list('a') append list at every index?
What I'm missing here?

Comment: When you initiate a variable using something like `[[]]*10`, the machine assigns the same location to each of these empty brackets. This means, that any change to one of these objects, would change all of them.

Comment: You have (the reference to) the same inner list 10 times your outer list. List references "point" to data - same references to the same data. `[[] for _ in range(10)]` creates 10 different lists. Use `print(*map(id,a))` & `print(*map(id,b))` to see what ids the inner elements got.